# The command '/bin/sh -c apk add --update redis' returned a non-zero code: 1

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I have tried to build the below Dockerfile, for the first time it built successfully but after that it is throwing the mentioned error. I am mentioning the Dockerfile and error below.

Dockerfile:

```
FROM alpine

RUN apk add --update redis

CMD ["redis-server"]
```

Error:

> Sending build context to Docker daemon  2.048kB Step 1/3 : FROM alpine
>   ---> e7d92cdc71fe Step 2/3 : RUN apk add --update redis  ---> Running in c03f589ce9da fetch
>   http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.11/main/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
>   ERROR: http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.11/main: temporary
>   error (try again later) WARNING: Ignoring APKINDEX.70f61090.tar.gz: No
>   such file or directory fetch
>   http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.11/community/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
>   ERROR: http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.11/community: temporary
>   error (try again later) WARNING: Ignoring APKINDEX.ca2fea5b.tar.gz: No
>   such file or directory ERROR: unsatisfiable constraints:   redis
>   (missing):
>       required by: world[redis] The command '/bin/sh -c apk add --update redis' returned a non-zero code: 1

Comment: Have you tried to retry later as the error suggests (`temporary error (try again later)`) ? Have you checked that you can successfully connect to the Internet, especially to http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.11/main ? By the way, there are official Redis images already available (for example `redis:5.0.7-alpine`), there should be no need to rebuild one.

Comment: @norbjd I retried after while but that didn't work out, also I have working internet connection. The links are also working fine. I also tried to build the below Dockerfile : 

`FROM node:current-slim

WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY package.json .
RUN npm install

EXPOSE 8080
CMD [ "npm", "start" ]

COPY . .`

But the error is :

npm ERR! request to https://registry.npmjs.org/bootstrap failed, reason: getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN registry.npmjs.org

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2020-02-18T11_01_49_170Z-debug.log

I am new to docker.

Comment: It looks like you cannot connect to the Internet **from** the container. Could you try 1) to ping something on the Internet from a container : `docker run --rm -it alpine:3.11 ping alpinelinux.org` and 2) run ping from `Dockerfile` (just add `RUN ping alpinelinux.org`). If this does not work, could you also try to ping the IP instead of the domain name and see what happen?

Comment: @norbjd i also think that i cant connect to internet from container, I ran first command and the result was `ping: bad address 'alpinelinux.org'` and for 2nd command the result was `Sending build context to Docker daemon  2.048kB
Step 1/2 : FROM ubuntu
 ---> ccc6e87d482b
Step 2/2 : RUN ping alpinelinux.org
 ---> Running in f94af01d102a
/bin/sh: 1: ping: not found
`

I am also unable to run `docker run busybox ping google.com`

Comment: Could you ping directly the IP from the container (you can get the IP by running `ping alpinelinux.org` from your host for example)?

Comment: @norbjd I am unable to so

Comment: So you got the error you mentioned only because you cannot connect to the Internet from a container. You wrote that it worked before (*for the first time it built successfully*), did you change something (host, network config, firewall, ...)? I suggest you to look for questions on SO or SuperUser about "no network in Docker container".

Comment: Okay thanks for the help I will search for the related queries

Comment: Hi @norbjd, the problem is resolved as my docker container was unable to resolve dns, so I disabled firewall and it worked. Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 0):

Create a file daemon.json in the location: /etc/docker/daemon.json

```
{
    "dns": ["8.8.8.8"]
}
```

Then restart docker:
systemctl restart docker

Answer (score -2):

Kindly check http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.11 in your browser, if you are able to access then you can access through your docker container as well.